# Multi-tenant SSL with Cloudflare and Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, web-applications, cloudflare

Im currently building an application that will reside at app.mydomain.com which is running on Heroku. All users will have their own entry points, like app.mydomain.com/client1, app.mydomain.com/client2, etc. I want clients to be able to setup their own domain (www.clientdomain.com) and cname it to their entry point. I understand this is pretty straight forward up until now.

All my DNS is handled by Cloudflare and I believe I can configure Cloudlfare into Full (Strict) mode, all I need to do is install their Origin Cert onto my Heroku dyno. This will ensure that all direct connects to my domain will be secure (going to app.mydomain.com/client1).

Question is, how does a client go about getting an SSL'ed connection for their domain; do I need to get a multidomain cert and start adding domains to it as I get clients, or am i supposed to install their cert onto Heroku (I believe I can only install 1 so thats a no go) or is it supposed to live on Cloudflare somewhere, or are there additional options I'm not seeing (I hope there are!).

Im not wondering what to do for my own domains, but rather, how do clients setup an SSL connection with their domains that resolve onto my servers.

This is rather perplexing!

The flow would be (I think):
User Browser -> Clients DNS -> (cname to) My Cloudflare -> Heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit - after clarification

> I'm currently building an application that will reside at
>   app.mydomain.com which is running on Heroku. All users will have their
>   own entry points, like app.mydomain.com/client1,
>   app.mydomain.com/client2, etc. Question is, how does a client go about
>   getting an SSL'ed connection for their domain; do I need to get a
>   multidomain cert and start adding domains to it as I get clients?

If you are going to use the same Heroku app for all of your clients (I think this is a bad idea by the way, but you might be required to) - then yes - you should get a multi-domain certificate and keep adding domains to it as your list of clients expand.

#### Original answer - which explains SSL + Load Balancing on Heroku.

> Im currently building an application that will reside at
>   **app.mydomain.com** which is running on Heroku. I was clients to be able
>   to setup their own domain **www.clientdomain.com** and cname it to mine.

You will need a wildcard certificate to cover your subdomain (for the app.mydomain.com). You'll have use that cert in heroku.

> ...all I need to do is install their Origin Cert onto my Heroku dyno.

You are correct - except it's not on your Heroku dyno, it's on your Heroku app endpoint. There's a good read here: https://serverfault.com/questions/68753/does-each-server-behind-a-load-balancer-need-their-own-ssl-certificate

> If you do your load balancing on the TCP or IP layer (OSI layer 4/3,
>   a.k.a L4, L3), then yes, all HTTP servers will need to have the SSL
>   certificate installed.
>
> If you load balance on the HTTPS layer (L7), then you'd commonly
>   install the certificate on the load balancer alone, and use plain
>   un-encrypted HTTP over the local network between the load balancer and
>   the webservers (for best performance on the web servers).

So you should install your SSL certificate to your Heroku endpoint and let Heroku handle the rest.

> Question is, how does a client go about getting an SSL'ed connection;
>   do I need to get a multidomain cert and start adding domains to it as
>   I get clients, am i supposed to install their cert onto Heroku (I
>   believe I can only install 1 so thats a no go) or is it supposed to
>   live on Cloudflare somewhere?

If you're referring to adding *servers* to your *service* from heroku, all you need to do is increase the number of web-dynos. Heroku will handle the load balancing in between these dynos. Your SSL certificate should be resolved in the load balancer so your dynos will be serving requests for the *same endpoint.* You shouldn't need another SSL certificate for the endpoint you've defined - as long as you're serving traffic from multiple dynos attached to it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that out. I dont think I properly explained what I'm looking for, so i've updated my original message. Im not wondering what to do for my own domains, but rather, how do clients get an SSL connection with their domains that resolve onto my servers.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. Why do you think its a bad idea to run my app on Heroku?

Comment: I didn't mean running your app on heroku is a bad idea, I mean running the same app for all of your clients assigned to different points is probably a bad one. Especially if they are doing different things. You're probably doing this to manage things easier, but that way you won't be updating one of your clients' code without updating the other one.

Comment: Oh i understand. Well each client actually runs on the same code base, and depending on their client id (or in this case, domain), we'd brand/render it differently. So in that case, I think one app is the best approach that way im not deploying X amount every time there's an update to the platform

Comment: Yep that’s ok then

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it looks like this might be a pretty solid solution to this issue...

https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-ssl-for-saas/

Comment: However, only available if you’re on the Cloudflare enterprise plan. And that’s certainly above $500/month.